# Charge Rate Myth?

Tags: camera, power-consumption, power-dissipation, over-discharge

Many websites post that charging your device with a high ampere charger will heat up the device and depreciate battery life. Is this really true. I have a sony nex camera that uses 5v 500ma input. Is it safe to charge it with a 2.1 A power bank. I thought the camera would only accept 500ma and ignore the rest. If this is the case what happens to the rest of the current. Is it dissipated into heat?

Comment: What kind of battery? What exactly do you mean by 2.1 ma power bank? Do you mean 2.1 A power bank? Do you mean 2.1 AHr power bank? I'm just wondering if you're trying to measure apples vs speed of apples.

Comment: Sorry my bad i meant 2.1 A power bank.

Comment: The battery is lithium ion

Comment: It wouldn't just "ignore the rest", it will simply draw less current. A supply capable of delivering 2.1A will only deliver 2.1A if the load resistance/impedance is small enough to allow it to flow.

Comment: Thanks. So it is completely safe to do the same ?

Comment: Batteries heating up more at higher charge rates is not a myth. That said, it is the battery *charger* that controls the charging current, not the chargers power supply (the power bank in this case). In most lithium battery powered devices the charger is integrated into the device itself, and using a higher amperage power source has no effect on the charging current whatsoever. The sites warning about excessive charging current talk about devices where you *can* set the charging current as you wish, like radio controlled models, but those are in the minority.

Answer (score 3):

Most if not all devices with a lithium ion battery have built in charge management. This means that the device will only accept the designed amount of current.

If the device is rated at 500mA then regardless of if the charger is 1A or 5A the device will only charge at 500mA.

The best way to think about it is that the load is a resistor. If the device will accept 500mA then it is like a 10 ohm resistor. As long as the supply is 5v, only 500mA will flow. Ohms law guarantees this.

Comment: I bought a usb amp meter and measured the rate of charge. The camera drew 1.2 amps instead of the .5A it drew while connected to the stock charger. So it seems like the camera doesnt have a inbuilt power management system. I guess then its unsafe to charge with the powerbank.

Answer (score 1):

The default charge rate for any USB 2 or earlier device is 500ma, as this is the maximum specified current for the USB standard. There are a number of different proprietary protocols used to negotiate higher charging rate (this is why charging a phone with a different phone's charger results in significantly longer charging times -- even though the charger is capable of delivering 2.1A, the phone will only draw 500ma unless it can confirm that the charger can safely supply more current lest the supply burn a fuse or shutoff power).

In the case that the phone is drawing 500ma, you can think of the phone as a 10 ohm resistor, which draws 500ma from a 5V source. The excess current "capacity" is not used. Were the phone to draw the full 2.1A, the presented impedance would be closer to 2.4 ohms. The way in which the phone achieves this is significantly more complicated as it uses various power electronics like DC/DC converters to provide the right voltage and current to the battery for charging. Remember that not all of this current is delivered to the battery because the phone must still run itself.

With respect to the heating question, the phone will not charge at a rate higher than its design specification and is equipped with thermal protection (were this to not be the case, your lithium battery would burn). Yes, the battery will deteriorate *slightly* faster if charged at a warmer temperature but it's definitely not worth fussing over. The difference is likely in single percentage points over the average lifetime of a typical electronic device. You're much better off making sure that you don't completely drain the battery or damage it in other ways.

Answer (score -2):

As vini_i  said

"Most if not all devices with a lithium ion battery have built in charge management"

**how to check:**

I guessing your power bank have two port 1A other is 2.1A.(or try with other charger)

charge with 1A and note down how much time(t1) it's take for full charge.

charge with 2.1A and note down how much time(t2) it's take for full charge.

if **t1=t2** approx then your device have power management.(your camera is safe)

if **t2 < t1** the port 2.1A will take approx half time to charge camera battery than t1.(unsafe)

> If this is the case what happens to the rest of the current. Is it
>   dissipated into heat?

yes, current will get converted into heat also reduce the life of battery.

### **if camera load is taking 2.1A and using only 500mA**

**How much heat?**

P=I*V

P=1.6*5 =8W (as 0.5A is used in charging)

8W heat is too much i'm guessing your camera does not have power management if 2.1A port will be charging your camera battery faster.

**How much is 8W heat ?**

Some of 8W light bulb provide more than 70-80 C of heat. if 8W directly converted into heat with Tungsten wire it will be above 100 C.

Comment: Very thorough. Made my inner physics nerd happy!

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  If the system charges faster, it just means that the charge controller will use a higher current, if available.  Most of the energy will be stored in the battery, and not heat up the system.  This assumes that the charge controller is close to the battery, and not integrated in the wall adapter.

Comment: charge controller may use higher current. agree.  My answer is based on "**if camera load is taking 2.1A and using only 500mA**"

Comment: -4. Your heat calculation is completely wrong. 1) final temperature has very little to do with heat capacity of the device, 2) your formula is wrong, heat capacity should be on the denominator,  3) your heat capacity figure is wrong, by 1 million times. 4) Kelvin = Celsius, you don't subtract 273

Comment: the link says "For temperature intervals rather than specific temperatures,
1 K = 1 °C".  You're thinking about the right stuff, but getting ahead of yourself. Read on some (diode) datasheets about heat dissipation from devices, usually in degrees per watt or milliwatt. 10 minutes is a long time for heating of electronics, they'll reach their final steady state value by then.